# What resources does request module use to execute requests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-request

If I have windows XP that doesn't support TLS. Can I still do a request (with a request module) to a server that requires TLS?

What does the request module use to do a HTTPS request?

Comment: It uses the TLS library in node.js, not the one shipped by your OS.

Comment: @slebetman I'd still count that as an answer , so you can put it as one.